# How to do an interlinear glossing to sentences written in two languages at the same time, e.g. sentences with code-switching?

Tags: interlinear-gloss, code-switching

I have sentences written in German and in the German sentences there are some Italian words and/or morphemes to find. It is like code-switching: When you start talking in German, then a word does not come to your mind and you use the equivalent of that word in Italian. Now I need to do an interlinear glosssing to these mixed sentences but I am unsure how to do that if you have two languages working in the sentences at the same time. How can I mark that the Italian words/morphemes are not German? 
(I apologize for any grammatical errors, English is not my mother language.)

Comment: I don't know whether there's any formality for this, but you could try typographical hints, like (consistently) different fonts or colors.